# C# memory leak?

Tags: c#, memory

I have a C# application that loops through a datatable, and pushes these into some locations such as Sage and a SQL table.

While it used to work fine, I'm inexplicably now getting Out of Memory exceptions after an hour or so of running it. I've noticed in the task manager, the memory usage rises by anbout 1mb every second, and keeps on going!

I was under the impression garbage collection would take of anything, but to be sure I ensure I dispose any objects after using them. I know without code it's hard to diagnose, but there's a lot of it and I'm looking more for general advice.

Comment: what edition of VS do you have? With the *better* ones you can use the profiler to try and locate what kind of objects you push onto the heap - that will help a lot.

Comment: Are you removing rows from the DataTable you have already dealt with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but to be sure I ensure I dispose any objects after using them

Dispose() is not directly related to memory management or leaks.

You'll have to look for unused objects that are still 'reachable'. Use a memory-profiler to find out.

You can start with the free [CLR-Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16273).

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of potential problems that spring to mind:

1. There is a large pool of objects that are left inelegible for garbage collection (i.e. they are still "reachable").  For example if you add an object to an list in every loop then the list will grown unboundedly and each element in the list will remain inelegible for garbage collection as long as that list is still reachable.  I'm not claiming that this is what is happening, this is just an example of how memory might be allocated and then left without being collected.
2. For some reason the garbage collector isn't doing a collection.
3. The high memory use is actually due to an unmanaged component that you are using in your application (e.g. via P/Invoke or COM interop).

Without seeing any code its tricky to give specific advice on how to fix your problem however reading through [Investigating Memory Issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163528.aspx) should give you some pointers on how to diagnose the memory problem yourself.  In particular my first step would probably be to examine performance counters to see if the garbage collector is actually running, and to check the various heap sizes.

Note that `Dispose` and the `IDisposable` interface is unrelated to memory use - its important to dispose of objects like database connections once you are done with them as it frees up any associated resources (e.g. handles) however disposing of objects that implement `IDisposable` is very unlikely to have an impact on memory use.

Answer (score 1):

Garbage collection can only get rid of objects that are no longer referenced from anything else.  In addition it can only get rid of *managed* objects - it has no control about memory created from native code you may be interfacing with.  These therefore are the two root causes for memory leaks in C# code.

The first thing to look at is perfmon.  Get the counters for the private bytes and the .net heap size for the process. If the heap size remains flat (or rises and drops) but private bytes keeps increasing you've got some native code allocating memory and not releasing it.

If the heap size just keeps growing then the leak is in your managed code and you'll need a profiler like ANTS, DotTrace or even WinDbg (with SOS extension) to inspect the heap and see what objects are lying about.

Answer (score 0):

The most popular "memory leak" on .Net platform is forgotten collection that repeatetly added in some infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

When you new something for temporary memory use.

Always use following way, it ensures calling dispose.

```
using (Someclass A = new Someclass())
{
   ....something about A
}
```

Someclass is a class implemented interface IDisposable

GC won't save you if there some part of unsafe code is involved(P/Invoke, Com etc..), and if there still a reference some where exists.

If you find memory leaking, use WinDbg will see what is in the heap.

This article may give you some help.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Memory_Leak_Detection.aspx