# .NET framework issue?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332283/c-memory-leak)

Sorry if this is not the right place to post this, seeing as it's not strictly code related.

Basically, since the beginning of this work, a program which has worked flawlessly before has suddenly started throwing Out of Memory exceptions. After checking out the usage, I discovered  the memory usage increases by a ridiculous 1mb per second! This happens on a part of the program that iterates over a collection, and calls many different methods - so it seems like these objects are staying in memory even after use.

What does this issue sound like to everyone else? I've been debugging the code, ensuring nothing's left open and all is disposed, but to no avail. I'm wondering if perhaps the .NET framework on the computer it runs from has become corrupt, and the garbage collection isn't running.

I plan to test on another computer later to hopefully prove this theory

Comment: [Please don't post the same question twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332283/c-memory-leak).  You can edit your original question if you have additional information.

Comment: Are you assigning any event handlers to the objects in these loops?

Comment: I would recommend using a profiler to find out where the problem is rather than just shoot in the dark.  There are a number of good options out there.  I have tried the Ants profiler from RedGate and it seemed to work well.

Comment: One consideration is that the problem has _always_ been present, just not apparent in the existing code; only manifesting itself when the size of the external(?) data has grown large enough.

Comment: I would suggest not getting too set on early theories yet (e.g. 1mb per second is not ridiculous at all, depending on what the code is doing).  In your place, I would ask myself a few questions:  Is it possible that it's actually a gradual change, and it's only now been noticed due to the errors?  What else has changed - is there more data in a DB that the system uses?  Does it rely on any 3rd party software that may have been patched recently?  Etc.

Comment: Post your code so we can have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Garbage collection will only clear up objects in the heap with no references left to them.  Although you've ensured you're disposing everything it'll also be an idea to specifically null any of these references to objects after use.

Perhaps you can post the troublesome code?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) tool. 10 days trial version is available.

Using it you can track what keeps the object reference to objects that should be removed from memory.