# High memory Usage problem for wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-management

I made a WPF application that opens the CSV file and does some operation that includes webscraping and gets some values that has type long.(0-10000000)

Now the issue is that when large list of about 2000 is opened then memory usage for software raises above 700MB in some cases 1G.

I am shocked to see this.

some things I think is that

1. If each entry of `csv`  file has long value associated with it it will take much memory.and single entry has approx 10-12 column each is long in type.now when there are huge row count then memory shoots
2. There are certain places in code that has a loop (on all csv rows) that creates a instance of custom class.i thought of having destructor then came to know that dot net manages memory automatically.

here goes code for loading CSV

```
    try
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path,Encoding.Default);
        labelRankCheckStatus.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate()
        {
            labelRankCheckStatus.Content = "Loading Data";
        }));

        string strline = "";
        string[] _values = null;
        int x = 0;

        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            x++;
            strline = sr.ReadLine();
            _values = strline.Split(',');
            if (x == 1)
            {
                textBoxKw1.Text = _values[12];
                textBoxKw2.Text = _values[14];
                textBoxKw3.Text = _values[16];
                textBoxKw4.Text = _values[18];
            }
            else if (x != 1)
            {
                if (_values[0] != "")
                {
                    Url info = new Url();
                    srNo++;
                    info.URL = idn.GetAscii(_values[0].ToString().Trim()); 
                    info.IsChecked = true;

                    info.TestResults = int.Parse(_values[1].Replace("%","").TrimEnd().TrimStart());
                        
                    info.PageRank= int.Parse(_values[2]);
                    info.RelPageRank = int.Parse(_values[3].Replace("%","").TrimEnd().TrimStart());
                        
                    info.Alexa= long.Parse(_values[4]);
                    info.RelAlexa = long.Parse(_values[5].Replace("%","").TrimEnd().TrimStart());
                        
                    info.Links= long.Parse(_values[6]);
                    info.RelLinks = long.Parse(_values[7].Replace("%","").TrimEnd().TrimStart());
                        
                    info.GIW= long.Parse(_values[8]);
                    info.RelGIW = long.Parse(_values[9].Replace("%","").TrimEnd().TrimStart());
                        
                    info.GIN= long.Parse(_values[10]);
                    info.RelGIN = long.Parse(_values[11].Replace("%","").TrimEnd().TrimStart());
                        
                    info.Kw1Indexed= long.Parse(_values[12]);
                    info.RelKw1Indexed = long.Parse(_values[13].Replace("%","").TrimEnd().TrimStart());
                        
                    info.Kw2Indexed= long.Parse(_values[14]);
                    info.RelKw2Indexed = long.Parse(_values[15].Replace("%","").TrimEnd().TrimStart());
                        
                    info.Kw3Indexed= long.Parse(_values[16]);
                    info.RelKw3Indexed = long.Parse(_values[17].Replace("%","").TrimEnd().TrimStart());
                        
                    info.Kw4Indexed= long.Parse(_values[18]);
                    info.RelKw4Indexed = long.Parse(_values[19].Replace("%","").TrimEnd().TrimStart());

                    info.DKwIndexed= long.Parse(_values[20]);
                    info.RelDKwIndexed = long.Parse(_values[21].Replace("%","").TrimEnd().TrimStart());

                    info.Info= _values[22];

                    info.srNo = srNo;
                    url.Add(info);
                }

            }
            dataGrid1.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate()
            {
                dataGrid1.Columns[2].Header = "URL ( " + url.Count + " )";

                try
                {
                    if (dataGrid1.ItemsSource == null)
                        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = url;
                    else
                        dataGrid1.Items.Refresh();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
                labelRankCheckStatus.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate()
                {
                    labelRankCheckStatus.Content = "Done";
                }));
            }));

        }
        sr.Close();
        labelRankCheckStatus.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate()
        {
            labelRankCheckStatus.Content = "Complete ";
        }));
    }
    catch (Exception c)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(c.Message);
    }`
```

Comment: can you post your code that load the csv file ? maybe we can find something here

Comment: Without code and proper data this is a meaningless question. Except that 1 GB is not really excessive. Use a profiler to find out _if_ you have a problem, and then what it is. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332283

Comment: About 2000 WHAT? Rows? Columns? Apples? Cars? And give us some code... From what you've written, it could be anything

Comment: "Memory usage for software" is not a passive state that just happens. The programmer is responsible for that.

Comment: After the code: You invoke actions on labelRankCheckStatus but not the more important actions on dataGrid1. An empty catch block is also a red flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of building in-memory copies of your large objects, consider a more functional approach where you stream data in, process it and output it to your database of choice. If you need to do operations on the old data, you can use an SQL database like Sqlite.

Creating managed objects for every single entity in your system is beyond wasteful, you won't need most of them.

Of course, if you have a lot of RAM, it might simply be that the GC isn't yet bothering to collect all your garbage because the memory isn't actively needed by anything. It's more likely that you're holding references to it though.

Comment: if you create object do we have option to de construct when we know its life is over

Comment: You have the option to stop holding on to it in an iron grip, if that's what you mean. Like in your example, a collection called `url` is holding on to your large objects, then you have two non-deterministic lambdas (plus the main function somehow) holding on to `url`. A lighter touch works best in a garbage collected world...

Comment: Of course the billion and a half strings you're creating doesn't help much either, consider unifying those trims and replaces into a single, hand-written, `StringBuilder`-based function.

Comment: Actually the String handling isn't so bad at all. The GC should deal with these very sort-lived strings very well. I would use `Trim()`, but not a  StringBuilder.

Comment: It's not *that* bad, sure, but it doesn't help either. It may or may not be a noticeable difference depending on how many times that loop runs.